# creating a barrel, smoke + fire creeping through barrel

Tags: mesh, fluid-simulation, collision, mantaflow

I am doing a test. I've got a hollow cylinder mesh that's supposed to represent a cannon barrel, and I have managed to get an emitter firing particles out of this cylinder. The cylinder constrains the particles being fired, which is good.

I also have blender emitting smoke and fire from these particles, which is also good.

However, the smoke and fire from the particles seems to be penetrating the barrel. I need my cannon barrel to block and contain the smoke and fire. It's bad that the smoke and fire just seem to go right thru the barrel.

Can anyone tell me how to set up the barrel object as either a collision or guide to constrain the flow of fire and smoke?

[image]